# how to enable ipv6 in redhat

Tags: networking, redhat, ipv6

i have installed snort with ipv6 supprt Version 2.9.0.2 IPv6 (Build 92)  in RHEL.
can anyone tell me how to enable ipv6 support in  linux
i tried

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

and

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
```

and did
service network restart
but still i get error

```
Bringing up interface eth0:  Global IPv6 forwarding is enabled in configuration
, but not currently enabled in kernel.
```

then i added `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` in `.etc/sysctl.conf`  , then rebooted
now i dont see  bthe above error msg but i dont see ipv6 forwarding from

can anyone please help

Comment: Is the ipv6 kernel module loaded? Have you tried `modprobe ipv6`?

Comment: Forwarding also requires writing firewall rulesets; have you written firewall rules to forward packets yet?

Comment: @sarnold
thanks for reply 
yes i have configured ip6tables  & the rule in  /etc/sysconfig/ip6tables.
i have tried two rules in ip6tables
-for all incoming tcp on eth0 , the target is  nfqueue 6
- for all incoing tcp on etho0 , the target is ACCEPT

both does not work

Answer (score 6):

For people looking to **enable** IPv6 forwarding, but getting *Global IPv6 forwarding is disabled in configuration, but not currently disabled in kernel*,
try adding `IPV6FORWARDING=yes` to `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

Answer (score 2):

To enable IPv6, you must have IPv6 support enabled in your kernel. Enabling IPv6 forwarding (as you are doing above) is useless in achieving that.

The following command will load the `ipv6` module:

```
# modprobe ipv6
```

After that, you should have IPv6 link-local addresses added to your interfaces. For example:

```
# ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::200:11ff:fe72:1aeb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If the above does not work, IPv6 support is not built in to your kernel, and must be upgraded. Consider running a modern Linux distro that includes IPv6 support out-of-the-box.

Comment: my kernel has ipv6 support.
i have verified using modprobe -c .
and i have assigned ipv6 addr to both interfaces.

Comment: Please provide the *complete* output of "ip -6 addr" in your question, and I will see if I can get any further.